# Binding HTML Input value in Ember v1.12 Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to use an HTML input in a component and need the value to be bound.The input helper causes various bugs when used on certain mobile devices, so that cannot be used.

The input that works in **Ember 1.13** or higher.

`component/name-input.hbs`

```
<input type="text" value={{name}} onChange={{action 'nameDidChange' value='target.value'}}>
```

`component/name-input.js`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    name: 'Jim',
    actions: {
        nameDidChange: function(value) {
            this.set('name', value);
        }
    }
});
```

How do I use an HTML input in **Ember 1.12** and still maintain the functionality?

I tried something like this but the input value is not passed to component's action:

`component/name-input.hbs`

```
<input type="text" value={{name}} {{action 'nameDidChange' value='target.value' on='change'}}>
```

`component/name-input.js`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    name: 'Dwight',
    actions: {
        nameDidChange: function(value) {
            this.set('name', value);
        }
    }
});
```

Here are two Twiddles, one in 1.13 that works as expected and one in 1.12 that does not work.

[Twiddle - 1.13](https://ember-twiddle.com/6f2154c3b2d890b446c2c43a31a1b7f8?openFiles=components.name-input.js%2Ctemplates.components.name-input.hbs)

[Twiddle - 1.12](https://ember-twiddle.com/9d8bc63e169c2914a3f2345b3d184178?openFiles=templates.components.name-input.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.name-input.hbs)

Comment: [1.13](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html) was the first version to include glimmer, I do not think this is possible in 1.12, you will have to use the input helper

Comment: You tried this  {{input value=name action='nameDidChange' on='change'}} ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot set value of action helper prior to Ember 1.13 (I would really be happy to be notified if I am wrong). As a result, your twiddle is not working for version 1.12 and I do not know a way to fix it.

What I suggest is kind of a workaround solution; which I did not like very much. I am posting it as an answer because it might just be the case it is an appropriate solution for you. Please see the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/eead75b347ebfc6a62a1b0605b2689ad) I created via modifying yours. I just used jquery to extract the value of the html input and set it to `name2` field of `name-input` component. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember 1.12.2, the event object is available in your action, which you can use to acquire the value for name-input:

```
actions: {
  nameDidChange() {
    const value = event.target.value; // <--
    this.set('name', value);
  },
},
```

I've created an [Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/b5b771313a000971c33527b90144e4aa?openFiles=templates.components.name-input.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.name-input.hbs) to demonstrate.